# update Cgridview using its column values manually

Tags: yii

I want to update cgridview using its column values,example if i want to filter name 'xxx' from grid how to perform this in

```
 $.fn.yiiGridView.update("editstructure-grid");
```

DataProvider Code:

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->searchbyID($base),
```

Model Search() code:

```
public function searchbyID($id)
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
        echo 'SEARCH ID===>'.$id;
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('crm_field_id',$this->crm_field_id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('display_rules',$this->display_rules,true);
        $criteria->compare('edit_rules',$this->edit_rules,true);
        $criteria->compare('type',$this->type);
        $criteria->compare('is_deduplication_field',$this->is_deduplication_field);
        $criteria->compare('is_std_phone',$this->is_std_phone);
            $criteria->compare('crm_base_contact_id',$id);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: An alternative if you don't understand yii's documentation... use datatables.net - it's great

Answer (score 0):

this is going to be a little complicated so please read carefully,

you need to send the clicked elements text back to your dataProvider, and there use that to filter out results and generate your grid again:

I'll leave selecting by that value to you,

lets refresh the grid and send back some data:

```
 $.fn.yiiGridView.update('some_grid', {
        data: 'name=tiny', // I'll assume you have selected the value and it's tiny
 });
```

but before that how to trigger this send method? one way is you could put it on the elements `onclick` attribute, when you give columns of gridview

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id' => 'some_grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'name' , 
                'header' => Yii::t('model','name'), 
                'value' => 'CHtml::link($data["name"], "#", array("onclick" => "RefreshMyGrid(".$data["name"]."); return false;"))',
                'type' => 'raw',
            ),
```

then your function becomes like this:

```
function RefreshMyGrid(Word){
     $.fn.yiiGridView.update('some_grid', {
            data: 'name='+Word, // Word is what you are sending now
     });
}
```

then in where ever that dataprovider is being populated (whether it's in models `search()` function or ...), get that value and use that to filter.

hope that helped :D

Update:

in `searchbyID` get the passed parameter:

```
 // name here is the parameter that we sent from the grid
 $param = Yii::app()->request->getParam('name' , null);
 if(!empty($param))
 {
      // t is alias for your table, also make proper join here
      $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN yourTable yt ON t.id = yt.id';
      // add a condition on joined table
      $criteria->addCondition('yt.id = "' . $param  . '"');
 }
```

Comment: actually im not showing crm_base_contact_id column in cgridview but used in model class, on ajaxsubmitbutton onsuccess im doing grid update by passed id as you suggested but data not filtering my code:                     
           array('success' => 'function(){
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update("editstructure-grid", {
            data: "crm_base_contact_id=1087",
     });
       }'))

Comment: where do you handle `crm_base_contact_id`? you need to handle that where you populate your data provider

Comment: crm_base_contact_id is a foreign key of another table

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: I am getting this error after pasted above code "CWebApplication and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getParam"."

Comment: it's actually `$param = Yii::app()->request->getParam('name' , null);`